# Gitweb - 404 - No projects found

Tags: git, centos7, gitweb

I have a DigitalOcean droplet with Centos 7 but I can't see my repos on my droplet.

I have a user `git` and inside the respective home folder I have the folder "projects": `/home/git/projects`

Inside that folder is a test repo initialized with: `git init --bare`

Here is my `gitweb.conf`

```
$projectroot = "/home/git/projects";
$git_temp = "/tmp";
$home_link = $my_uri || "/";
$home_text = "indextext.html";
$projects_list = $projectroot;
```

Here my sites-availables file:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  git.apselom.com;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/git.apselom.com.access_log main;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/git.apselom.com.error_log info;

        location /gitweb.cgi {
                root /var/www/git/;
                include fastcgi_params;
                gzip off;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $uri;
                fastcgi_param GITWEB_CONFIG /etc/gitweb.conf;
                fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
        }
    location / {
                root /var/www/git/;
                index gitweb.cgi;
        }
}
```

With those, I only get the error: `404 - No projects found`.

Comment: Do not link us to an image.  Instead, tell us that you get a 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that the user your web server is running as is unable to access your git repositories.

What's odd is that you said you're using CentOS 7, but CentOS 7 ships with Apache httpd, and what you have their looks like a Lighttpd configuration.  The `gitweb` package for CentOS ships with an Apache configuration file, so that using it is basically:

- Install the package(s):

  ```
  yum install gitweb httpd
  ```
- Create your `git` user and make sure the `apache` user will be able to access things:

  ```
  # useradd -c 'git user' git
  # usermod -a -G git apache
  # su - git <<EOF
  mkdir projects
  git init --bare projects/project1
  git init --bare projects/project2
  EOF
  # chmod -R g+rwX /home/git
  ```
- Edit `/etc/gitweb.conf` to point to the projects directory:

  ```
  our $projectroot = "/home/git/projects";
  ```
- Start the web server:

  ```
   systemctl enable httpd
   systemctl start httpd
  ```

And you're good to go:

```
$ links http://localhost/git/
[...]
   Project            Description             Owner   Last Change                                  
   project1 Unnamed repository; edit this... git user No commits  summary | shortlog | log |       
                                                                  tree                             
   project2 Unnamed repository; edit this... git user No commits  summary | shortlog | log |       
                                                                  tree
```

The key part, though, is ensuring that your web server has appropriate permissions on your `/home/git` directory.  If you're not using Apache, figure out what user your web server is using and then substitute that in the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add apache to the group of git.

```
usermod -a -G git apache
```